# Improving the accessibility of jQuery UI AutoComplete

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm looking for suggestions on how to make the jQuery UI Autocomplete suggestions read out in a screen reader as the user is arrowing through them.  I notice that the textbox itself doesn't lose focus, so the reader simply reads it's contents over and over.  Based on my requirements, I cannot have the textbox value change when a suggestion is arrow'd to.

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Please show some code of what you have tried.

Comment: I confirm this behavior. It's due to the fact that JAWS (for instance) doesn't exit forms mode automatically, nor is the text field updated. Probably we should file a bug.

Comment: The following post will help some perhaps: http://www.marcozehe.de/2014/03/11/easy-aria-tip-7-use-listbox-and-option-roles-when-constructing-autocomplete-lists/